# -ms-user-select: none bugged in IE11

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-11

-ms-user-select: none is bugged in IE11. It is possible to select the text by selecting text appearing prior to the unselectable text first and then continuing with the marking. Se [gif](https://i.gyazo.com/9f01f4cf501d074899549bba1dd0373e.mp4), [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12839002/c5jsLnbL/3/), [image](https://i.gyazo.com/ca612d48aaf5e326d1c2bc95348b539a.png).

[caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=CSS%20user-select) does not report this bug.

Is this a known bug? Is there a way to fix this with only CSS or do I need to use JavaScript? I'm using version 11.0.9600.18537.

HTML:

```
<p>You can mark this</p>
<div>You can mark this in IE</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
     -moz-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none !important;
          user-select: none;
}
```

Comment: Just fired up a vm with win7/I.E11 which I have for testing and in the fiddle you provided you cannot select the text directly, there is no highlight. However you can select something that is selectable and then drag over the text that is not selectable and you will see the highlight.

Comment: @run yards This is what I meant, as demonstrated by in the GIF and this is the behavior I want to avoid. This is not the case in Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/user-select and the specification for ***none*** parameter:

> The text of the element and sub-elements will not be able to be selected. Selection can contain these elements.

Comment: It works as intended in Firefox, but not in IE. I cannot select in Firefox (intended) but I can in IE (not intended). To be exact, I cannot select the element directly, only if I highlight the text of the selectable element and continue with the selection over the non-selectable element. This is the bug.

Comment: I don't think it is a bug, specification is clear that selection can "contain these elements". Try to select it in Firefox, press CTRL + C (copy) - and while the text is not highlighted, it will be selected. IMHO, IE is actually being more user friendly on this one.

Comment: So "Selection can contain these elements." means that the elements cannot be visually selected (i.e. highlighted) but can still be selected and thus copied?

Comment: Please see comment on question by @run yards for another (better?) explanation.

Comment: In that case, I guess your best option is to use a plugin, and check if the selection (range) contains the text you do not want to select. I have used https://github.com/timdown/rangy and can confirm it works.